# Leaflet easyButton - Button Text is not Displaying (Can't debug addTo)

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, leaflet

I'm having trouble with leaflet-easyButton. I have installed it into my project with:

```
npm install --save leaflet-easybutton
```

Thereupon, a folder exists inside the /node_modules and I can import it into my component:

```
  import "leaflet-easybutton/src/easy-button";
```

To add a button to my map, I call it like so, and add a Button Text with the **title** element, but when the button displays on the map, there is no text. The onClick() works fine though! So I realized that **title** is actually a tool tip. Ok fine. But I wanted to see inside the code at runtime.

```
   L.easyButton({
     position: 'topleft',
     leafletClasses: true,
     states: [
       {
         stateName: 'center',
         onClick: function(btn, map){ alert('This popup works!') },
         title: 'Button Text',
         icon: 'fa-globe'
       }
     ]
   }).addTo( my_map );
```

I tried to debug the "addTo" statement, hoping to see what happens inside, but the debugger does not go into it, rather, it skips over it.

Strange? So I thought perhaps I could debug it if I changed **addTo** to **addToTemp** in the files in leaflet & leaflet-easyButton. Doing that did absolutely nothing. In fact, **addTo** still worked, even though I renamed it everywhere else and addToTemp did not. So now it got me thinking that the leaftlet code is somewhere completely different.

Where is it then, if not in /node_modules? A search for it in my Project did not result in anything. I'm confused?? Does anybody have any advice here?

Thanks in advance for your time:
Moa

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```js
L.easyButton("<div>Your Text</div>", function (btn, map) {
  // Code here...
}).addTo(mymap);
```

If you want to add some custom HTML along with states, you will probably need to modify the original source code of the `easybutton` library as follows:

```js
function State(template, easyButton){

  this.title = template.title;
  this.stateName = template.stateName ? template.stateName : 'unnamed-state';


  // Check whether we supply some custom markup:

  if ( template.markup ){
    this.icon = L.DomUtil.create('div','');
    this.icon.innerHTML = template.markup;

  } else {
    
    // build the wrapper
    this.icon = L.DomUtil.create('span', '');
    L.DomUtil.addClass(this.icon, 'button-state state-' + this.stateName.replace(/(^\s*|\s*$)/g,''));
    this.icon.innerHTML = buildIcon(template.icon);
  }


  this.onClick = L.Util.bind(template.onClick?template.onClick:function(){}, easyButton);
}
```

Usage:

```js
      L.easyButton({
        position: "topleft",
        leafletClasses: true,
        states: [
            {
                stateName: "center",
                onClick: function (btn, map) {
                    alert("This popup works!");
                },
            markup: "<div>Hello World</div>"
          },
        ],
      }).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: My biggest issue is not being able to debug and see where the code is.

Comment: What about checking the source code? https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton/blob/cd53db586a10d5a9c4efed003327cad29f4760bf/src/easy-button.js#L61

Comment: If you have npm installed leaflet-easybutton you'll find a node_modules/leaflet-easybutton folder with a src/easy-button.js. You can add a debugger statement there.

Comment: I did. But not once did it hit the "debugger" statement. Like I mentioned above, I even changed "addTo" to "addToTemp". It not only didn't hit the code, it ignored addToTemp; it honoured "addTo" still and nowhere can I find where the "real" addTo is??

Comment: Is there a node_modules/leaflet-easybutton folder?

Comment: Changing "addTo" to "addToTemp" won't work as there is no "addToTemp" method available in return value of the 'easyButton()' method.

Comment: Yes there is a folder and I've changed easy-button.js and easy-button.ts. I've also change leaflet.src.js in the leaflet folder. My project does not appear to be using these folders, but I don't know how to tell?

Comment: What bundler are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252291/discussion-between-moa-and-kostas-minaidis).

Comment: I have noticed my leaflet programs are in a webpack (bundler) and contain an old version. How do I edit/update those specific programs in the webpack?

Answer (score 0):

This question is wrong, so I will close it.

The problem is not **leaflet** or **leaflet-easyButton**, rather, its **webpack**.

When I load the map, it uses files from a webpack, instead of /node_modules/leaflet & /node_modules/leaflet-easybutton, but I don't want to use the files in the webpack anymore.

So how do I update my webpack to use the correct files? That's my real question.

Thanks,
Moa